# Vue route page animation and transtion not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Hi my vue 3 project routing page animation and transition not working

```
    <template>
  <app-header />

  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }" :key="$route.fullPath">
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <component :is="Component" />
    </transition>
  </router-view>

  <app-foother />
  <div v-on:click="pageTop()" class="downUpArrow">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
  </div>
</template>
```

My router-link Header component not I am added router link add not working transtion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<template>
  <div id="nav">
    <!-- routes -->
  </div>
  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <component :is="Component" />
    </transition>
  </router-view>
</template>

<style>
/* ... */

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

[Repo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-router-transition-s23qd?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Chris i did this but it still doesn't work

Comment: Okey Chris not problem

Comment: I suggest copying my `template` and `script` to see if it is working in your app, then add other component and attribute one by one to figure out what's wrong.